# How can I move the relative position of an image in a grid?

Tags: image, xaml, xamarin.forms, grid, overlay

I am creating a car app that lists cars and their prices, model, speed, etc. I wanted to position the price over an image of the car, like so:

[image: Perfect diagram]

To do this, I created a grid and allowed the image to fill the entire thing while forcing the text (with a frame around it) into a lower column/row. However, I am ending up with white space on the top of the graph. Take a look. I set the grid to a background color of blue for easier viewing.

[image: Full app diagram]

The issue here is the aspect ratio, because an image that *did* fill the entire grid would cut off the sides. The size of the whitespace is equivalent to the overlay, so if I had the overlay any lower that would result in more whitespace on both sides.

**Note:** Some of the cars have different aspect ratios, so this has to be a fix that would work for other images as well.

**Note 2:** This has to be a relative position fix, since obvious methods like setting the image's margin to `-100` wouldn't work on other resolution screens and would probably get me fired.

**The question:** How can I relatively (e.g. make it work on every screen) force the image to the top of the page while still keeping the same aspect ratio and keeping the overlay?

Here's the front-end.

```
<StackLayout>
    
    <!-- Image and cost grid-->
    <Grid BackgroundColor="Blue">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="63*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="35*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="75*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Source="{Binding ImageLocation}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
        
        <Frame BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <Label Text="{Binding Cost}" FontSize="Large" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="Black"/>
        </Frame>
        
    </Grid>
    
    <!-- Information about the car -->
    <StackLayout Padding="15">
        <Label Text="{Binding Company}" FontSize="Large"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Model}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
    </StackLayout>
    
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Are those car images have different sizes (Or the first row of Grid is supposed to be fixed height)? And you also want the price frame to adjust the height accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your frame not the image.

1. Set Grid content in one row.
2. Set Frame `VerticalOptions` to `End`
3. Set Frame `HeightRequest` and `Margin` (minus value).
4. Set bottom StackLayout `VerticalOptions` to `FillAndExpand`

```
        <StackLayout>

            <!-- Image and cost grid-->
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Blue" ColumnDefinitions="63*, 35*, 2*">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageLocation}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>

                <!-- Shape the Frame here -->
                <Frame HeightRequest="40"  Margin="0,0,0,-20"  VerticalOptions="End" 

                       BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="5" Grid.Column="1" >
                    <Label Text="{Binding Cost}" FontSize="Large" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="Black"/>
                </Frame>
            </Grid>

            <!-- Information about the car -->
            <StackLayout Padding="15" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Label Text="{Binding Company}" FontSize="Large"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Model}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
```